# setInterval still stil firing events after unloadMovie / removeMovieclip

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have made a movieclip browser that is able to load different movieclips from a navigation tree. I noticed that any movies that have intervals in them (setInterval()) will keep on going even if I unload or even remove the Movieclip.

Given the fact that I have no control over the loaded movieclips: how can I COMLETELY REMOVE the movieclip including the intervals ??

As a work around I made this function that tries to eliminate all running intervals, but that is not the way it should be done (or is it?). It seems to work well though...

```
var LastCleared=-1;
ClearAllIntervals = function(){
//You MUST clear the intervals or they will not be deleted. Every setInterval returns a higher number.
    Highest = setInterval(function(){},100); //Get highest intervalnumber
    i=Highest;
    while(i>LastCleared){
        trace("***************clearing interval:"+i);
        clearInterval(i--);
    }
    LastCleared=Highest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

LastCleared/Highest will always fire, because you never clear it.

Also what is the scope of your ClearAllIntervals() function? Is it possible that a new instance is getting created that doesn't remember the previous value of LastCleared?

Note that I haven't been able to find anything that documents that setInterval returns sequential numbers, as you seem to think it does. However, since setInterval doesn't "belong" to anybody, you can't override it to capture those interval id's.

Finally, I think AS3 in the later versions of the player has functionality to release loaded movies from memory, and it certainly has sand boxing that prevents loaded MC's from attaching themselves to anything in the loading MC.